# Auth triggered cloud function (create user) doesn't execute

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Can't understand what am I doing wrong.
I've deployed the functions successfully and I can see them in the project's dashboard, but the function doesn't execute when a new user is authenticated.

The purpose of the function is to create a new user object in the database for this new registered user.

When I register a new user (I've been using the google signin) - nothing happens in the database. When I go to the authentication tab though, I can see a new user was authenticated.

This is my `index.ts` document:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

export const createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)=>{
const newUser = new MyUser(user.uid, "Friend","", new Array, Array("en"),0,0,0 )
return db.doc("users/"+user.uid).set({newUser});
});

class MyUser{
    uid: String;
    first_name: String;
    last_name: String;
    communities_list: Array<string>;
    lang_list: Array<string>;
    reputation: Number;
    join_date: Number;
    last_activity: Number;
    constructor(uid:string, first_name:string, last_name:string, communities_list:Array<string>, lang_list:Array<string>, reputation:Number, join_date:Number, last_activity:Number) { 
      this.uid = uid;
      this.first_name = first_name; 
      this.last_name = last_name; 
      this.communities_list = communities_list; 
      this.lang_list = lang_list; 
      this.reputation = reputation; 
      this.join_date = join_date; 
      this.last_activity = last_activity; 
   }  
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing (in detail please) that suggests that the function should be executed?  Please edit the question to explain.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the object I was trying to set. After digging a it (new to cloud functions) I saw in the cloud functions log this message:

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "MyUser" (found in field newUser). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).
```

After searching for a solution for this I realized I need to change this line:

```
return db.doc("users/"+user.uid).set({newUser});
```

to this

```
return db.doc('users/'+user.uid).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newUser)));
```

and now it works.